# Matlab python integration on Apple Silicon

Tags: python, matlab, conda, apple-m1, mini-forge

I installed Python on my Apple M1 using miniforge

```
brew install --cask miniforge
```

but I am not able to use a Conda environment on MATLAB:

```
>> pyenv('Version', '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/matpy39/bin/python3')

ans = 

  PythonEnvironment with properties:

          Version: "3.9"
       Executable: "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/matpy39/bin/python3"
          Library: "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/matpy39/lib/libpython3.9.dylib"
             Home: "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/matpy39"
           Status: NotLoaded
    ExecutionMode: InProcess

>> py.list({1})
Unable to resolve the name py.list.
```

However, if I use Macs built in python version, it does work:

```
>> pyversion('/usr/bin/python3')
>> py.list({1})

ans = 

  Python list with no properties.

    [1.0]
```

I am not sure what to do so that MATLAB uses a specific Conda environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew builds native ARM/M1 binaries on Apple Silicon now. Matlab is an x64 binary running under Rosetta emulation. I suspect the problem is that you can't load an ARM library (Homebrewed Python) into an x64/Rosetta process (Matlab). I bet macOS's system Python distribution is a "universal" build or similar thing that can load in to either kind of process.

You can probably get this to work by installing an x64 version of Miniforge or Anaconda outside Homebrew, and telling Matlab to load that.

Have a look at https://www.anaconda.com/blog/apple-silicon-transition.

Comment: I agree, but they should still install Miniforge (osx-64) not Anaconda.

Comment: Deferring to you here and added Miniforge as the first suggestion in the answer.

Comment: thank you, that worked! I downloaded the macOS x86-64 installer for Anaconda and it works